SqlAlchemy listeners on AWS lambda/serverless
I'm using SqlAlchemy with FastApi on top of AWS lambda.
I came across a problem that an elegant solution to it will be SqlAlchemy listener function (on insert/update). But then I was wondering how can this work on lambdas/serverless.
Something like this:
@event.listens_for(SomeMappedClass, "before_insert", propagate=True)
def my_listener_function(*arg):
    pass

would probably be problematic on a lambda.
Does anyone have any experience with this? Tried and failed or found a workaround that they can share?
